# wp_editor doesn't save styling

Tags: wp-editor

After editing/styling i save the post and this doesn't keep the styling instead give me plain text.

```
        <?php
    $content = get_post_meta($post->ID,'principle_duties',true);
    $editor = 'principle_duties';
    $settings = [
        'textarea_rows' => 10,
    ];
    wp_editor($content,$editor,$settings);
     ?>
//////////////////
  if ( isset( $_POST['principle_duties'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'principle_duties', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'principle_duties' ] ) );
    }
```

[[image: edited one[1]]

[image: after save]

Comment: Has the value of the `meta` `principle_duties` definitely got the HTML in it, at the time of fetching it from the database? Can you see HTML in the `meta`'s value in the database?

Comment: Please [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/247538/edit) your question to include how you're saving `principle_duties` post meta.

Comment: @SamuelElh updated the post. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stripping all HTML tags before saving `principle_duties`.

```
sanitize_text_field()
```

This function strips all HTML tags, so the value being stored has no HTML. That's why it's coming out as totally plain text.

To sanitize `wp_editor` I would use `wp_kses()`.

See here on how to use it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses

For the `allowed` HTML tags, you can simply pass the `global` variable `$allowedposttags` which I believe would be the same way WordPress does things with it's editor in posts/pages' content.